# Can't control DC motor with PWM on Raspberry Pi

Tags: pwm, raspberry-pi, brushless-dc-motor

I recently bought a 24V brushless DC motor from ebay (link: https://www.ebay.com/itm/392320171299).

[image: 24V BLDC motor]

I've been able to connect it to a 24V power source and it runs. I've been trying to control it via the connected PWM cable (white one, see link) but it doesn't work.

I'm using a raspberry pi and the https://docs.golemparts.com/rppal/0.12.0/rppal/pwm/ library to setup PWM. I've even measured the output pin and the voltage seems to change with my settings. However the motor still won't respond, it just runs at full speed.

Does the raspberry pi not provide the PWM voltage required (3.3V) required for this 24V motor?

Comment: Did you connect the 0V of the motor to 0V of the raspi?

Comment: What is the 0V? Is that the yellow wire (FG)? And by 0V do you mean ground on the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Black wire on the motor to GND as raspi. Pay attention to the length of the black wire on the motor - if you extend it, then voltage drop might be an issue. In which case it may cause the raspi to fail. A raspi isn’t intended to control things in the real world without protection.

Comment: Is that OK to do with a 24V motor? Also the motor's red wire connects to a 24V power supply. I have extended the PWM wire, but only about 6 inches.

Comment: Current flows in a loop so the raspi gnd needs to be connected to the motor gnd/0V. I don’t know why raspi calls its 0V GND - so very confusing as not all GNDs are grounded. Nevertheless be aware that voltage drops can cause problems.

Comment: Hmm, well that must be the problem right there. So right now I have the motor on a dedicated power supply, and the RasPi powered with a wall usb plug. Can I just connect the RasPi's ground pin to the dedicated power supply's ground with an additional wire?

Comment: Yes. You need the extra wire to make those electrons flow!

Comment: Well I've added a wire from ground to the raspberry pi's 3rd pin (ground) but the motor still runs at full speed no matter the duty cycle on the pwm. Here's a picture of my setup: https://imgur.com/a/nGtoCJf

Comment: How do you know the raspi is outputting pwm? The port pin may have already been damaged. Use a multimeter to measure the voltage at 0% and 100% pwm. With and without the white wire connected.

Comment: Check your PWM frequency. The motor's datasheet specifies 50Hz to 50 kHz range. RPi should allow you to set the PWM frequency yourself.

Comment: The voltage on the rpi when the white wire is not connected is exactly as expected, ex, when set to 20% duty, voltage is .660V, at 100% it is 3.3V. will have to check when the wire is connected tomorrow (but iirc it is like 1-2v and moves very little with % duty change). I've tried the PWM frequency at 500Hz and 50kHz, neither works.

Comment: @Mu3 where did you find the datasheet? Ebay page specifies 500-1000Hz.  And PWM amplitude not mentioned, so my guess it should be a level shifter to match voltage of motor. Simply BJT may help.

Comment: @user263983 I googled the part number and this datasheet came up: http://www.dynetics.eu/CMS/Docs/Nidec/nidecbrushlessdc22h.pdf I don't really trust ebay sellers with providing accurate information about electronics...

Comment: I've seen that datasheet before while trying to troubleshoot this issue. I was specifically interested in the PWM voltage, which is within the range I'm providing (see the bottom where it says PWM input).

Comment: @Kartman when the motor is on, with the setup in the picture, the voltage at 0% duty is .6V and at 100% duty it's .9V.

Comment: I've got it working. I wired the Raspberry Pi's input power to the same power supply. It seems either I had a bad connection when just connecting the PS's ground to the Raspberry Pi's ground pin, or maybe there is some kind of ground isolation, so you need to connect the Pi's input ground to the power supply's ground. Thx @Kartman, I did this based off your recommendations. Note: This motor uses inverted polarity PWM. Also this motor definitely doesn't support 50kHz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Black wire on the motor to GND on raspi. Pay attention to the length of the black wire on the motor - if you extend it, then voltage drop might be an issue. In which case it may cause the raspi to fail. A raspi isn’t intended to control things in the real world without protection.